# Emacs Actionscript 3 indentation for functions defined inline in an arglist

Tags: actionscript-3, emacs, closures, indentation

I'm using the [actionscript-mode-connors.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/actionscript-mode-connors.el) for indenting Actionscript 3 code in emacs.

I have most things figured out, but one thing bothering me is when I use an inline closure as a function argument, the indentation of the interior of the function is screwed up.

For example:

```
var foo:int = some_function(
  bar,
  baz,
  function():void {
                              return qux();
                            },
  zap);
```

I want return qux() to be a single indent from the function declaration on the previous line, not a single indent from the open paren. The indentation of 'bar' used to be screwed up too but I fixed that with

```
(add-hook 'actionscript-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
        (c-set-offset 'arglist-close 0)))
```

Typically here I would use C-c C-s to figure out what syntactic symbols I need to change, but the problem on the 'return qux()' line is that the syntax context is

```
((arglist-cont-nonempty 731 758) (brace-list-intro 731))
```

where those numbers refer to the 'some_function' line. 'arglist-cont-nonempty' seems like a mistake, and it seems like it should be 'arglist-cont', since there's nothing after the open paren on that line. I can't change the indentation for 'arglist-cont-nonempty' since that would affect the case where the open paren does not end the 'some_function' line as well.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an indirect answer?  It seems as though you're relatively comfortable with the C indentation machine.  You might want to use advice around `'c-guess-basic-syntax` to recognize the particular configuration and modify it to be what you think would make the most sense for that situation.

If you take a look at this answer for an [indentation customization for comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462209/emacs-c-mode-indent-problem-with-doxygen-style-comment/1463049#1463049), I essentially did the same thing, only at the point of indentation.

Regarding your specifics, I cannot reproduce the same failure you have, my indentation for that chunk of code (in `'actionscript-mode` with your two changes) looks like:

```
var foo:int = some_function(
  bar,
  baz,
  function():void {
    return qux();
  },
  zap);
```

Also, the syntax for the `return qux();` line is: `((brace-list-intro 319))`.

It seems that your hunch is correct (that the `arglist-cont-nonempty` list is the problem), and changing the output of `'c-guess-basic-syntax` seems like it would be a viable solution.

Can I also point out the obvious test?  Have you  started without any customizations and loading just action-script?  I did so with the latest action-script and Emacs 23.1 and got the results you see above.  Tested with `M-x c-version` showing both `5.31.3` and `5.31.7` (the later is distributed with Emacs 32.1).

Comment: I have tried this without any customizations. But perhaps there is a better actionscript mode I should be using. Which actionscript-mode.el are you using? There seem to be a lot floating around, I have tried a couple so far but neither is great.

Comment: I used the one you provided in the question (I don't know actionscript-3 at all).

Comment: Maybe it's a different c-mode.

Comment: @jrockway I don't know JavaScript either.  :(  Man I've got to spread my wings...

Comment: actionscript != javascript, unfortunately. actionscript has actual classes, inheritance, static typing, various other things.

Comment: @jrockway I'm using cc-mode 5.31.5, what are you using?

Comment: Ok, I should have listened harder to you in the first place. I tried with a fresh .emacs and it's working but some other customizations are not. Thanks - this is my fault at some point. I'll binary search from here.

Comment: @lacker Yah, that's why I added that comment at the end.  Most of the time when I think I've found a bug, I'm wrong...

Comment: Yep. I thought I had tried with no customizations, but I missed a different place where I had made another customization... :-/

Answer (score 2):

I would use [espresso-mode](http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/) for ActionScript.  It indents your example correctly.

Comment: espresso mode does indent that properly. it doesn't do as much syntax highlighting, though, e.g. member function declarations.